# How to delete rows based on threshold, but organized by another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I am trying to take my dataframe and delete each row, corresponding to values in another row, based on whether or not each category of rows contains a value exceeding a threshold. While I feel this should be a simple "if" conditional statement, I am confused over whether this is actually as simple as I think it might be, or if this is much more complex. I am using python and pandas. I will demonstrate with an example below to better communicate this problem.

I have the following dataframe:

```
Date              Category      Value
---------------------------------------
2015-06-02               1          2
2015-06-03               1          9
2015-06-04               1          2
2015-06-05               2          2
2015-06-06               2          8
2015-06-07               2         11
2015-06-08               2          2
2015-06-09               4          2
2015-06-10               4          5
2015-06-11               4         12
2015-06-12               4          2
2015-06-13               6          2
2015-06-14               6          8 
2015-06-15               6          2 
2015-06-16               8          2
2015-06-17               8          6
2015-06-18               8         10
2015-06-19               8          2
```

As you can see, rows are categorized by a certain ID corresponding to the "Category" column. So in this example there are 5 "Categories": "1", "2", "4", "6", "8". It does not matter that they do not increase by 1 for each category, so long as the categories are kept distinct. And so, you will see a patter, given that this is date chronological data, for each category, the value starts at 2, has some values in between, however many, and ends at 2. So each category has values "in between" values of 2. What I want to do is take the dataframe and remove the categories where between the two values of 2, for that unique category, where there no value that is >= 10. As you can see, this would mean removing Category 1 (it has a 9 between the 2's), and removing Category 6 (it has an 8 between the 2's). Of course, there can be any number of values in between the 2's, but at least one of them must be >= 10 And so I would want to produce the following dataframe:

```
Date              Category      Value
---------------------------------------
2015-06-05               2          2
2015-06-06               2          8
2015-06-07               2         11
2015-06-08               2          2
2015-06-09               4          2
2015-06-10               4          5
2015-06-11               4         12
2015-06-12               4          2
2015-06-16               8          2
2015-06-17               8          6
2015-06-18               8         10
2015-06-19               8          2
```

How can this be done in python? While I would think I would write a conditional statement that says "if value in df['Value'] < 10, then remove", but I am not sure how to organize this based on the "Category" column like I mentioned.

Comment: In your input data, all categories start with a `3`, not a `2` as in the description...

Comment: I am sorry! I meant to replace all `3` values with `2`! I just fixed this. Sorry for the confusion. I updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the groups start/end with `2/3`, the condition `df['Value'].ge(10)` already search for those rows in the middle. You only need to do `groupby().transform('any')` on that condition:

```
mask = df['Value'].ge(10).groupby(df['Category']).transform('any')

df[mask]
```

Output:

```
          Date  Category  Value
3   2015-06-05         2      3
4   2015-06-06         2      8
5   2015-06-07         2     11
6   2015-06-08         2      3
7   2015-06-09         4      3
8   2015-06-10         4      5
9   2015-06-11         4     12
10  2015-06-12         4      3
14  2015-06-16         8      3
15  2015-06-17         8      6
16  2015-06-18         8     10
17  2015-06-19         8      3
```

Comment: Sorry! I just realized I made a mistake in my post. I meant to replace all `3` values with `2`! So it is just a matter of values being between `2`s, with no need to be between `3`s. I just updated my post. Sorry for the confusion! Would still applying your code suggestion work?

Comment: @LostinSpatialAnalysis yes, both `2` and `3` are less than `10`, so doesn't effect the condition `>=10`.

Answer (score 0):

The `groupby` in pandas can be used as an iterator that returns subsetted dataframes so that operations can be done on each sub-dataframe. Take this example:

```py
cats = reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [[i]*4 for i in range(4)])
vals = [random.randint(0, 20) for _ in range(len(cats))]
df = pd.DataFrame({"category": cats, "values": vals})
```

This random dataframe can look like this:

[image]

You can then iterate over and apply logic specifically to each sub-category like this:

```py
res = []
for _, sub_df in df.groupby("category"):
    if sub_df["values"].max() >= 10:
        res.append(sub_df)
if res:
    df = pd.concat(res)
```

This code looks at each subset and then appends it to a list if it meets the criteria. This list of dataframes (if not empty) then is concatenated into one dataframe. Note: the order here will now be ordered by the grouped variable. If this bugs you then just used `df.sort_index()` to re-sort it by original index.